# Windows - how to echo a line verbatim in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo

I'm looking to generate a dynamic SAS file from a bat file so I can pass in some variables from the commandline. I'm hoping to do this,

```
echo //**$1** JOB 99999,'IMS-MXG',CLASS=3,REGION=100M,                       00010026 > DETAIL_EXAMPLE
echo //             MSGCLASS=Z,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),NOTIFY=&SYSUID                 00020036 >> DETAIL_EXAMPLE
echo //JCLLIB JCLLIB ORDER=(SCBP.MXG.JCLLIB)                                 00030036 >> DETAIL_EXAMPLE
echo //MYSTEP EXEC MXGSAS,WORK='1500,500',                                   00040036 >> DETAIL_EXAMPLE
echo //       OPTIONS='PRINT=REPORT SYSPARM="SITE=CA,ZONE=PRIME"'            00050036 >> DETAIL_EXAMPLE
echo //DETAIL   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=**$2**                                       00060036 >> DETAIL_EXAMPLE
echo //REPORT   DD SYSOUT=*                                                  00070036 >> DETAIL_EXAMPLE
echo //SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                                  00080036 >> DETAIL_EXAMPLE
echo //SYSIN    DD *                                                         00090036 >> DETAIL_EXAMPLE
echo OPTIONS  LINESIZE=90 ERROR=1 PAGESIZE=32767 PAGENO=1 NUMBER NODATE      00100036 >> DETAIL_EXAMPLE
echo   SYMBOLGEN NOLABEL MISSING='' COMPRESS=YES                             00110036 >> DETAIL_EXAMPLE
echo   OBS=MAX REPLACE FORMDLIM='-' FORMCHAR='|-,???+????+=|-/\<>*';         00120036 >> DETAIL_EXAMPLE
echo                                                                         00130036 >> DETAIL_EXAMPLE
echo                                                                         00140036 >> DETAIL_EXAMPLE
echo DATA _NULL_;                                                            00150036 >> DETAIL_EXAMPLE
```

And get this,

```
//**$1** JOB 99999,'IMS-MXG',CLASS=3,REGION=100M,                       00010026
//             MSGCLASS=Z,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),NOTIFY=&SYSUID                 00020036
//JCLLIB JCLLIB ORDER=(SCBP.MXG.JCLLIB)                                 00030036
//MYSTEP EXEC MXGSAS,WORK='1500,500',                                   00040036
//       OPTIONS='PRINT=REPORT SYSPARM="SITE=CA,ZONE=PRIME"'            00050036
//DETAIL   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=**$2**                                       00060036
//REPORT   DD SYSOUT=*                                                  00070036
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                                  00080036
//SYSIN    DD *                                                         00090036
OPTIONS  LINESIZE=90 ERROR=1 PAGESIZE=32767 PAGENO=1 NUMBER NODATE      00100036
  SYMBOLGEN NOLABEL MISSING='' COMPRESS=YES                             00110036
  OBS=MAX REPLACE FORMDLIM='-' FORMCHAR='|-,???+????+=|-/\<>*';         00120036
                                                                        00130036
                                                                        00140036
DATA _NULL_;                                                            00150036
```

But, this is what I'm getting,

```
  //**$1** JOB 99999,'IMS-MXG',CLASS=3,REGION=100M,                       00010026 
  //JCLLIB JCLLIB ORDER=(SCBP.MXG.JCLLIB)                                 00030036 
  //MYSTEP EXEC MXGSAS,WORK='1500,500',                                   00040036 
  //       OPTIONS='PRINT=REPORT SYSPARM="SITE=XX,ZONE=PRIME"'            00050036 
  //DETAIL   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=**$2**                                       00060036 
  //REPORT   DD SYSOUT=*                                                  00070036 
  //SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                                  00080036 
  //SYSIN    DD *                                                         00090036
  OPTIONS  LINESIZE=90 ERROR=1 PAGESIZE=32767 PAGENO=1 NUMBER NODATE      00100036 
    SYMBOLGEN NOLABEL MISSING='' COMPRESS=YES                             00110036
```

Notice how line 2, 12, 13, and 14 are missing. I'll probably need to look into escaping some of those characters on line 12, but the other lines are leaving me clueless on why they aren't appearing.

**Is there a way to echo these lines verbatim?**

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Just tried this out in a batch file on Windows 7 and it displays all the whitespace. What version of Windows are you using? Are you sure those are spaces or tabs?

Comment: Did you try the lines with leading whitespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
echo(//**$1** JOB 99999,'IMS-MXG',CLASS=3,REGION=100M,                       00010026 > q36271044.txt
echo(//             MSGCLASS=Z,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),NOTIFY=^&SYSUID                 00020036 >> q36271044.txt
echo(//JCLLIB JCLLIB ORDER=(SCBP.MXG.JCLLIB)                                 00030036 >> q36271044.txt
echo(//MYSTEP EXEC MXGSAS,WORK='1500,500',                                   00040036 >> q36271044.txt
echo(//       OPTIONS='PRINT=REPORT SYSPARM="SITE=CA,ZONE=PRIME"'            00050036 >> q36271044.txt
echo(//DETAIL   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=**$2**                                       00060036 >> q36271044.txt
echo(//REPORT   DD SYSOUT=*                                                  00070036 >> q36271044.txt
echo(//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                                  00080036 >> q36271044.txt
echo(//SYSIN    DD *                                                         00090036 >> q36271044.txt
echo(OPTIONS  LINESIZE=90 ERROR=1 PAGESIZE=32767 PAGENO=1 NUMBER NODATE      00100036 >> q36271044.txt
echo(  SYMBOLGEN NOLABEL MISSING='' COMPRESS=YES                             00110036 >> q36271044.txt
echo(  OBS=MAX REPLACE FORMDLIM='-' FORMCHAR='^|-,???+????+=^|-/\^<^>*';         00120036 >> q36271044.txt
echo(                                                                        00130036 >> q36271044.txt
echo(                                                                        00140036 >> q36271044.txt
echo(DATA _NULL_;                                                            00150036 >> q36271044.txt

TYPE "q36271044.txt"

ECHO =====================================
DEL "q36271044.txt*" 2>NUL

(
 echo(//**$1** JOB 99999,'IMS-MXG',CLASS=3,REGION=100M,                       00010026
 echo(//             MSGCLASS=Z,MSGLEVEL=(1,1^),NOTIFY=^&SYSUID                 00020036
 echo(//JCLLIB JCLLIB ORDER=(SCBP.MXG.JCLLIB^)                                 00030036
 echo(//MYSTEP EXEC MXGSAS,WORK='1500,500',                                   00040036
 echo(//       OPTIONS='PRINT=REPORT SYSPARM="SITE=CA,ZONE=PRIME"'            00050036
 echo(//DETAIL   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=**$2**                                       00060036
 echo(//REPORT   DD SYSOUT=*                                                  00070036
 echo(//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                                  00080036
 echo(//SYSIN    DD *                                                         00090036
 echo(OPTIONS  LINESIZE=90 ERROR=1 PAGESIZE=32767 PAGENO=1 NUMBER NODATE      00100036
 echo(  SYMBOLGEN NOLABEL MISSING='' COMPRESS=YES                             00110036
 echo(  OBS=MAX REPLACE FORMDLIM='-' FORMCHAR='^|-,???+????+=^|-/\^<^>*';         00120036
 echo(                                                                        00130036
 echo(                                                                        00140036
 echo(DATA _NULL_;                                                            00150036
)>q36271044.txt

TYPE "q36271044.txt"

GOTO :EOF
```

Two different ways to do it (and you didn't mention the syntax-error reports)

In the first, redirectors and other characters with special meaning need to be escaped, that is `|><&` require a leading `^`.

In the second, there is a technique of creating the file containing the `echo`ed output without perpetually appending. The syntax

```
(
a series of statements
)>filename
```

creates the file **but** you also require to escape `)` as it's all within parentheses.

`%` needs to be escaped by `%` not `^`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing out all the symbols that need to be escaped, I think that was causing all the problem with the second way of writing to a file when I tried earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo.` instead of `echo`

That will preserve your leading whitespace and will also protect you against situations where you meant to echo an `'@'` sign (`echo@`... has special interpretation, but echo. will not prepend a `'.'` and is safe)

```
C:\Users\username>echo.//    Some setting                    00123567>some_file

C:\Users\username>echo.//   Some other stuff                 00123568>>some_file

C:\Users\username>echo.                                      00123569>>some_file

C:\Users\username>echo.                                      00123570>>some_file

C:\Users\username>more some_file
//    Some setting                    00123567
//   Some other stuff                 00123568
                                      00123569
                                      00123570

C:\Users\username>
```

Comment: Hi LD, thank you for your response! I realized that in my instance (line 2), I need to escape the & sign. Thank you for trying this in command prompt, I should've tried that earlier. I'm still hoping to be able to find a way to echo those lines word by word without need to escape anything though, if possible.